# Matplotlib: Removing the numbering on an axes of the subplot, created with fig.add_subplot()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I there away to remove the numbering on one of the axes of the subplot using matplotlib, assuming I use `fig.add_subplot()` for creating subplots (as opposed to `plt.subplots()`)?

Here is the example code:

```
index = 0
fig = plt.figure()

for q in range(3, 24, 4):
    index  += 1;
    f = './npy_train_{:02d}_0013.npy'.format(q)
    images = np.load(f)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 3, index)
    ax.set_xlim((0,1)); ax.set_ylim((0,1))
    ax.plot(images[0, 0, :, 0], images[0, 1, :, 0], 'bo', label = 'train_{:02d}_0013.npy'.format(q))
    ax.set_title('npy_train_{:02d}_0013.npy'.format(q))
```

I would like to know how to get rid of the numbers on x-axis in the first row of subplots.

Comment: What would be the reason not to use `plt.subplots` ? This is working nicely with or without shared axes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ax.set_xticklabels([])` to remove the tick labels from a given subplot. Then you just need to know which subplots to apply this to. In your case, its those with indices 1, 2 and 3. So, you can just use `if index < 4:`, like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

index = 0
fig = plt.figure()

for q in range(3, 24, 4):
    index  += 1;
    f = './npy_train_{:02d}_0013.npy'.format(q)
    images = np.load(f)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 3, index)
    ax.set_xlim((0,1)); ax.set_ylim((0,1))
    ax.plot(images[0, 0, :, 0], images[0, 1, :, 0], 'bo', label = 'train_{:02d}_0013.npy'.format(q))
    ax.set_title('npy_train_{:02d}_0013.npy'.format(q))

    if index < 4:
        ax.set_xticklabels([])

plt.show()
```

[image]